# Ubuntu 14.10 x64 usb printer HP DeskJet AllInOne not detected

Tags: usb, printing, 14.10, hp

I bought a new HP Deskjet 1510 AllInOne printer. When I connected via USB, it appears as an un-recognized device in dmesg output.

```
usb 3-2: device not accepting address 27, error -71 usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Also lsusb doesn't show it.

I suspect this is why even HPLIP is not able to configure the printer. So, my question is how can I fix this problem?

Is there any driver / kernel module that needs to be installed for the USB HP Printer to be detected properly?

### EDIT1:

I tried adding `use_both_schemes=y` to us core options:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/options 
options usbcore use_both_schemes=y
```

This also had no effect.

Comment: Yes, I did install HPLIP. HPLIP doesn't recognize any printer. It actually cant, unless USB core recognizes is too.

Comment: Perhaps this would work for me: https://urukrama.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/usb-drive-not-recognised-error-71/

Comment: This doesn't work either `options usbcore use_both_schemes=y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB Cable was faulty. I replaced the USB cable and it just worked. I had to install HPLIP after the printer was detected, and nothing more.

Output of `dmesg`:

```
[ 5898.551540] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 5898.680036] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=c111
[ 5898.680046] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5898.680051] usb 3-4: Product: Deskjet 1510 series
[ 5898.680055] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: HP
[ 5898.680058] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[ 5898.681435] usblp 3-4:1.1: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 17 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0xC111
[ 5899.897408] usblp0: removed
[ 5899.898097] usblp 3-4:1.1: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 17 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0xC111
[ 5940.759735] usblp0: removed
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb  | grep -i hewl
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 03f0:c111 Hewlett-Packard
```

Comment: and could you provide the installation step to made your answer perfect :P